# Older post not indexed, new post indexed right away?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, googlebot, google-index

I have  a post I created yesterday that was indexed rather quickly by Google. However, I have two other post that I created within the past 4 days that are  not indexed and I cannot find a trace of them within the SERPs.

Any idea what my cause this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't predict when Googlebot goes to your site for indexing.

Googlebot follows links it finds over the Internet and it can find a link to your site (and goes to your new article) right away after publishing. Googlebot may also be not going to your site for several hours, days, etc. It's the way Googlebot works.

To optimize a quick indexing, you can:

- put a lot of links to your site (or to your new article) over the Internet (on crawlable places)
- often publish content on your site
- submit new URLs through a sitemap to your Google Webmaster Tools account
- ping Google for indexing a new URL

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to get indexed your post. Please follow mentioned below:

1. Update XML sitemap in Webmaster Tools
2. Fetch your post through Webmaster Tools
3. Insert Meta index tag to your post
4. Post new content regular basis

Comment: Could you explain how a meta index tag can speed up the indexing of a page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Robots Meta tags into your pages. It will tell robots to index the content of a page, and/or not scan it for links to follow. You can also put revisit meta tags, It will tell the spider to come back to your website and index it again.  Here is the both tag