# How to improve Googlebot's indexing frequency?

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot, search-engine-indexing

I am experiencing low indexing issues on our website from several months. Google is not indexing the website fast enough. The changes we make take 1 or 2 months to get reflect in search engine. It's a big website we have done everything: updating sitemap/break in many sitemaps and tried to fetch those URL's but got nothing it showed last cached a month ago. How to make Google index out site more often?

Few pages I am mentioning 
https://www.eworldtrade.com/
https://www.eworldtrade.com/importers/mushroom-buyer/

Also, I don't see the drop down on this url which mentions cache in every url in search engine

[image]

Comment: I don't think this should be [on hold]. This could potantially be relevant to any site, even though @Asad is, naturally, referring to a his specific one.

Comment: This might help: [Older post not indexed, new post indexed right away?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60509/older-post-not-indexed-new-post-indexed-right-away)

Comment: 1 to 2 months for less popular pages on a large site sounds about right to me.  We'd all like faster, but that is just how Google works.  To get more content indexed and get your site crawled more often you need to wait until the reputation of your site increases, mostly though external links.  See [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: As far as the Google cache goes, see: [Google not showing cache option on the following url in SERP results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119972/google-not-showing-cache-option-on-the-following-url-in-serp-results)